# MySQL Dynamic Query Statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to accomplish something like the following:

```
cursor = db.cursor() 
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO media_files (%s, %s, %s, %s ... ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,   ...)', (fieldlist, valuelist))
cursor.commit()
```

I have 2 lists, fieldlist and valuelist which each contain the same number of items. What is the best way to generate a dynamic MySQL query statement where the collumns are stored in fieldlist and the values are stored in valuelist?

Comment: After posting my answer it occurred to me that your lists might be of variable length. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO media_files (%s) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s,   ...)' % ','.join(fieldlist), valuelist)
```

To make it clearer:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO media_files (%s) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s,   ...)' % ','.join(fieldlist)
cursor.execute(sql, valuelist)
```

Comment: To make sure im understanding correctly, there should only be one '%s' for columns even if there are multiple fields in fieldlist and there should be one '%%s' for each value that is in valuelist? Something like this, assuming 4 columns and values?

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO media_files (%s) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s)' % ','.join(fieldlist), (valuelist,))

Comment: If you use string interpolation, you lose the sql escaping that MySQLdb does for you if you pass a parameter sequence

Comment: @Trent I edited the syntax. @Rob Cowie The adapter will not substitute the column names, or better, it will substitute they wrapped in quotes which will result in a syntax error. So the column names will have to be passed before the adapter gets the sql string.

Comment: @Trent You're absolutely right. The erroneous escaping of the field names didn't occur to me. Nice one.

Comment: thanks everyone for the feedback. @Clodoaldo, the code isn't quite executing as expected. When i break it into two steps as you describe in the second "clearer" solution, the cursor.execute(..) fails. The sql variable looks correct (has columns filled in but no values yet). I even tried adding a middle step where I interpolate sql a second time with % ','.join(valuefields). Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The cursor expects parameters to be passed as a single sequence, so you need to combine - in order - the field and value lists.

`itertools.chain()` does exactly that however it returns a generator and I'm not sure if `cursor.execute()` will accept that as it's param sequence. Try it. If it fails, wrap it with `list()`

```
import itertools
sql = 'INSERT INTO media_files (%s, %s, %s, %s ... ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,   ...)'
cursor.execute(sql, itertools.chain(fieldlist, valuelist))
```

**EDIT:**

This solution will **not** work. This would cause the field names to be escaped and wrapped with quotes which would cause an sql syntax error.
I'll leave this answer as it might serve as a useful example but look to @Trent's answer for the solution.