# MySQL dynamic query in Python

Tags: python, mysql, dynamic

Can anyone tell me the proper way in which I can execute dynamic MySQL queries in Python?

I want to do dynamic queries for both CREATE and INSERT  statement. I have referred another post here:

[MySQL Dynamic Query Statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589414/mysql-dynamic-query-statement-in-python)

But it didn't work.

Here is my attempted code:

```
sql="create table %s (%%s, %%s, %%s ... )" % (tablename,''.join(fields)+' '.join(types))
cur.execute(sql)
```

where 'field' is the fieldnames stored in a list and 'types'  are the fieldtypes stored in a list.

Comment: The error I got :
     TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: as a side note I would recommend that you use an ORM like SQL Alchemy, it would make your life easier and ensure that you are making safe requests, http://www.sqlalchemy.org

Answer (score 0):

It may be confusing that both Python and the `MySQLdb` DB API use `%s` to denote substitution.  For the DB API, it is primarily used to avoid SQL injection attacks.  In a `cursor.execute()` statement, it only makes sense to use `%s` where *string* substitution is required.

eg.

You want the following sql to be executed:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (myfield INTEGER);
```

not

```
CREATE TABLE 'foo' ('myfield' INTEGER);
```

Something like the following might be suitable:

```
field1_name_and_type = 'myfield VARCHAR(100)'
sql="create table %s (%s)" % (tablename, field1_name_and_type)
cur.execute(sql)
```

Then, when you want to `INSERT` into the table, use the `%s` in the execute statement to escape strings.

```
my_malicious_sql = input()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%%s)' % tablename, my_malicious_sql)
```

In this example, the first argument to `execute()` is expanded like this, if `tablename == "foo"`:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)', my_malicious_sql)
```

Then, the MySQLdb library will correctly escape any string in `my_malicious_sql` to avoid in SQL injection errors and insert the text into the database table.

Comment: what I want is to execute dynamic mysql query, not the static

Comment: @rahul The last example in my answer shows a partly dynamic query. Ie The table name is dynamic.  It's up to you to build the query. What exactly are you trying to achieve?