# dynamic mysql insert statement in python

Tags: python, mysql

I need to update columns values in csv to mysql database and the csv values are dynamic for one file it may be 10 columns and for other it may be 5 columns.

my understanding in python we need to use list also this question raised earlier is similar to my requirement but here the values are static so it can be predefined where's in my case being dynamic need to a solution to have %%s under VALUES to be multiplied according to my column values dynamically.

[MySQL Dynamic Query Statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589414/mysql-dynamic-query-statement-in-python)

```
   ds_list=['name','id','class','chapter','MTH','YEAR']

   vl_list=['xxxxx','978000048','x-grade','Science',mar,2017]

   sql = 'INSERT INTO ann1 (%s) VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s)' %    ','.join(ds_list)

   cur.execute(sql, vl_list)

   conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if you have two lists, one with headers and the other with values – you can create yourself dynamic INSERT query.

```
query_placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(vl_list))
query_columns = ', '.join(ds_list)

insert_query = ''' INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s) ''' %(query_columns, query_placeholders)
```

and then execute & commit your query by passing list with values in query.

```
cursor.execute(insert_query, vl_list)
```

Comment: Hi An se thanks for your answer when I execute i receive ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: can you print the resulting 'insert_query' and 'vl_list' and copy paste it here?

Comment: sorry , made mistake while specifying the table name it works. is there a similar way to do in update statement also instead of insert statement so that where clause can be used in query.

Comment: Hi An Se, actually I copy paste your code and made it working, if you can explain in short what code actually does, it would be helpful to write code myself for update statement.