# Python MySQL Dynamic Insert - Column Name as Variable, Values as Variables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am trying to create a function that populates a MySQL table.
The function receives several variables as inputs:

```
Symbol
Var_Date
Stat_Name
Stat_Value
```

The value of Stat_Name changes as the code runs, eg Enterprise_Value, Profit_Margin, EBITDA - these are the column names within the table.
Stat_Value is the data that goes into the rows.

This code requires one Column Name as a variable, and three values as variables.

I found this previous article which looks promising, but I haven't been able to make it work as of yet.
[dynamic mysql insert statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499191/dynamic-mysql-insert-statement-in-python/46499251)

I have pasted my attempt at the code below:

```
dbname = "mydb"
var_table = "exc"

symbol = 'ABC'
var_date = '20200629'
stat_name = 'Enterprise_Value'
stat_value = '12345'

def funPopulateTables(symbol, var_date, stat_name, stat_value):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd=mypass, db=dbname)

    my_cursor = conn.cursor()

    query_placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(stat_value))
    query_columns = ', '.join(stat_name)

    add_word = ("INSERT INTO {table} " "(Symbol, Date, (%s)) " "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)") %(query_columns, query_placeholders)
    data_word = (symbol, var_date, stat_value)
    my_cursor.execute(add_word.format(table=var_table), data_word)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

funPopulateTables(symbol, var_date, stat_name, stat_value)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the error that I get when I run the code:     add_word = ("INSERT INTO {table} " "(Symbol, Date, (%s)) " "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)") %(query_columns, query_placeholders)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: This will be easier if you do it in two stages. First create the SQL string with the table and column name filled in. Print that string and check it is correct. Then stage 2 is to execute it, passing the values as parameters.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

After following the advice from khelwood, this code is now working:

```
dbname = "mydb"
var_table = "exc"

var_date = '20200629'
symbol = 'AAB'
dict_stats = {'Enterprise_Value' : '12345', 'EBITDA' : '67890'}

def funPopulateTables(symbol, var_date, key, stat):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd=mypass, db=dbname)

    my_cursor = conn.cursor()

    add_word_temp = str("INSERT INTO {table} " "(Symbol, Date, ") + key + str(") " " VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    print(add_word_temp)
    add_word = str(add_word_temp)
    data_word = (symbol, var_date, stat)
    my_cursor.execute(add_word.format(table=var_table), data_word)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


for key in dict_stats:
    print(key)
    stat = dict_stats[key]
    print(stat)
    funPopulateTables(symbol, var_date, key, stat)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It would make more sense for you to post the working code in your answer, not in your question.

Comment: Thanks again. I've had instances where I've written the working code in the answer and the moderator tells me to update the original code I posted instead. Let's see what happens with this one.